# Test coverage gem for ruby that checks lines are actually covered

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I used a tool that would help me improve test coverage by checking that the lines of the file that I am testing actually mattered to the spec.

It was done by disabling each line in the tested file and seeing if any tests failed. If no tests failed after a line was disabled, it was considered not covered.

I can't seem to find it today, maybe it was in a different language. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be sure: How is the result different from the de-facto standard [rcov](https://github.com/relevance/rcov) or [simplecov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) ? This in case you were not aware of them and was looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: I am aware of those. Coverage tests don't change your code to find things that don't affect tests.

Answer (score 1):

Found it, its called **Mutation testing**:

> Mutation testing is not an alternative to line coverage. While line coverage asks “what percentage of our code is run by our tests,” mutation testing asks “what code can I change without breaking your tests?” Mutation testing tools answer this question by applying and testing small modifications to your application.

Article:
https://blog.blockscore.com/how-to-write-better-code-using-mutation-testing/

RailsConf talk: http://confreaks.tv/videos/railsconf2014-mutation-testing-with-mutant